# Explanation of Scala LinkedList code

Tags: scala

I found an example of code building a `LinkedList` from scratch in Scala and I could not understand the last line in the example. Here is the example :

```
scala> class MyList (val head : Any, val tail : MyList) {
     | def isEmpty = (head == null && tail == null)
     | def length : Int = if (isEmpty) 0 else 1 + tail.length
     | override def toString: String = if (isEmpty) "" else head + " " + tail
     | }
defined class MyList

scala> var list = new MyList (null, null)
list: MyList =

scala> list.length
res3: Int = 0

scala> list.isEmpty
res4: Boolean = true

scala> list = new MyList ("ABC", list)
list: MyList = ABC

scala> list.length
res5: Int = 1

scala> list.isEmpty
res6: Boolean = false

scala> list = new MyList("XYZ", list)
list: MyList = XYZ ABC

scala> list = new MyList ("123", list)
list: MyList = 123 XYZ ABC

scala> list.tail.head
res7: Any = XYZ
```

I dont understand why `list.tail.head` prints "XYZ". In fact I cannot reason out what `list.tail.head` should print a priori given the definition of the `class MyList` as given. Any help in understanding what is going on would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that constructor parameters defined with `val` are public member and thus accessible (have a look [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch04s03.html)). Quoting from the link:

> If the field is a val, Scala generates only a [public] getter method for it.

`head` contains the one element that we consider the first, `tail` another list of elements that we consider the tail. It's a recursive structure where an instance of an object contains a reference to another instance of the same object.

In your example, after you built a list after the other, it's like you have (this is not actual code):

```
MyList(
  head = "123"
  tail = MyList(
    head = "XYZ"
    tail = MyList(
      head = "ABC"
      tail = MyList(
        head = null
        tail = null
      )
    )
  )
)

list.tail = MyList(
  head = "XYZ"
  tail = MyList(
    head = "ABC"
    tail = MyList(
      head = null
      tail = null
    )
  )
)

list.tail.head = "XYZ"
```

Comment: Ah! I didnt know that constructor params auto define public members. And the writing out of the MyList data structure at the end helped clarify the picture immensely. thanks!! shouldnt the last tail be a tail = MyList (head = null tail = null). if yes, then if you make that edit I can accept your answer.

Comment: They define getters and/or setters if you use `val` or `var` in the definition, otherwise not. Yes, it should, I'll correct it